# Preventing u-tube effect of drilling fluid

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, viscosity

Say you have two cylinders, one fixed bigger outer cylinder and the other is free (lets say a straw with a tapered end 1/3 from the bottom. As you push the straw into the medium (fairly dense viscous medium (not water)), the medium starts to come out the top of the straw. Can you put a certain density of fluid in the straw to continuously add more straws until you reach the bottom of the bigger cylinder without it flowing over the top, particularly when the straw is higher than the fixed cylinder.

Comment: Welcome blockie. This might fit better on our [engineering.se] site. Be sure to take their tour, read-up in their help centre about what's on topic before posting.